# How do u get Eq3 from Eq2&Eq1

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

[image]

I keep getting the wrong results by subbing eq1 into eq2
It’s from Kleppner’s an introduction to mechanics 2nd edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted text effectively combined two Lorentz transformations into one single transformation to identify the factor $\beta$, which is related to the velocity by $\beta=\frac{v}{c}$, thus the relativistic velocity addition formula. There are a few mistakes, so I'll give you the full proof (this is equivalent to the text).

The first Lorentz transformation can be expressed by a matrix

$$
\Lambda_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_1 & -\gamma_1 \beta_1 \\
-\gamma_1 \beta_1 & \gamma_1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}u_1'\\u_4'\end{bmatrix} = \Lambda_1 \begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_4\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Similarly for the second transformation we have

$$
\Lambda_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_2 & -\gamma_2 \beta_2 \\
-\gamma_2 \beta_2 & \gamma_2 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}u_1''\\u_4''\end{bmatrix} = \Lambda_2 \begin{bmatrix}u_1'\\u_4'\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The matrix representation for the combined boost is therefore
$$
\Lambda_3 = \Lambda_2 \Lambda_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_1\gamma_2 (1+\beta_1\beta_2) & -\gamma_1\gamma_2(\beta_1+\beta_2) \\
-\gamma_1\gamma_2(\beta_1+\beta_2) & \gamma_1\gamma_2(1+\beta_1\beta_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

From this it is clear that

$$
\gamma_3 = \gamma_1\gamma_2(1+\beta_1\beta_2)
$$

and

$$
\beta_3 = \frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}{1+\beta_1\beta_2}.
$$